# Moq: Unable to cast

Tags: c#, moq

I have the following mocks:

```
var MockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var MockPrincipal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();

MockHttpContext.SetupGet(h => h.User).Returns(MockPrincipal.Object);
```

The error occurs when testing this line:

```
var user = (CustomPrincipal)httpContext.User;
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'IPrincipalProxy5c6adb1b163840e192c47295b3c6d696' 
to type 'MyProject.Web.CustomPrincipal'.
```

My CustomPrincipal implements the IPrincipal interface. So can anybody explain why I am getting that error and how I can solve it?

Comment: In addition to my answer, here's a tip:  var is a shortcut to use only when you know what's going on... if you use var when you don't know what's going on, your code will suffer. (although using var is not the root of this issue)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I marked Yuriy's answer as the correct one because he explained that moq creates it's own class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you can't cast it is because MOQ is creating its own class which implements IPrinciple. Specifically the IPrincipalProxy5c6adb1b163840e192c47295b3c6d696. But just because both of those classes implement the same interface, does not mean you can cast from one class to another. Why do you need to cast it? Why can't you use the members on IPrinciple provided by MOQ?

Comment: Because my CustomPrincipal has some extra methods which I need. Before I had my own interface ICustomPrincipal which I used to mock but that didn't work either.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer. I had a hunch Moq would create it's own class but wasn't sure so that's why I asked.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Same reason this won't work

```
class WoodDuck : IQuack {}
class RealDuck : IQuack {}
//
IQuack myQuacker = new WoodDuck();
RealDuck myDuck = (RealDuck) myQuacker;
```

Comment: And the reason is...?

Comment: @testing_22 A wood duck is not a real duck. You get an InvalidCastException